# Webpage to paginated, text PDF

Tags: browser, pdf, web, screenshot, screen-scraping

I have been looking for a simple way to convert a website to a paginated PDF with selectable text.

I've tried many browser extensions but they only allow for PNG, full-page screenshots and print with system dialog breaks the style and layout.

The closest to success I've been so far is with [Web Snapper](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23929/web-snapper), but the issue is that the app gets the content by itself, meaning it can't access some page (e.g: Logged-in view of a user profile).

Comment: Have you tried Adobe print-to-PDF utilities?

Comment: Chrome has a built-in save to pdf feature. Just hit Ctrl-P and change destination to "Save as PDF". If the layout of the page is an issue and you just want plaintext, use a plugin like [Mercury](https://mercury.postlight.com/) first and then save to pdf

Comment: P Fitz: Yes I've tried and had same issues, either bad formatting or can't access some page.

wysiwyg: I need the page layout & design to be identical to the page, as mentioned, the built-in print/save to PDF break styles & layout, and Mercury seems to only grab the text.